# Какая веб-cms сейчас наиболее популярная в рунете?

Tags: cms

Какая веб-cms сейчас наиболее популярная в рунете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никакая, есть просто множество известных: MODX, WordPress, Drupal, Joomla, Bitrix, UMI и многие другие. Откройте сайт вакансий, фриланс, форумы веб-разработчиков и сами посмотрите, о чем больше говорят.

UPD. Статистика как обычно - выбирают под задачу или что больше знают. У каждой свои преимущества, недостатки и круг решаемых задач. Вопрос о том, какая популярнее или лучше ответа не имеет, поэтому ваш вопрос я закрыл. А так полно информации по разбору в интернете(обратите внимание на вторую ссылку):

1. http://habrahabr.ru/post/151879/
2. http://www.cmsmagazine.ru/library/items/cms/choice_cms/
3. http://mainspy.ru/vybor_cms_dvizhka_dlya_sajta
4. http://habrahabr.ru/post/92607/

Comment: что они известные мне итак ясно. а статистика их выбора меня как раз волнует.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress самая популярная. Далее Joomla.